# Summation of two rows and paste it to another workbook in one column

Tags: excel, vba

Hello I have an issue with the summation of 2 rows and paste it to another workbook in a column.

meaning lets say

- row 26,column 3 adding row 27,column 3 value
- row 26,column 4 adding row 27,column 4 value
- and so on until column 12
- 3 4 5 6 7 row
- 2 6 7 8 9 row
- column
- 5
- 10
- 12
- 14
- 16

I've tried separating the x source range summing up and trying pasting over but it could not work.

It says

> run-time error '13':type mismatch

This is my code:

```
Sub transfer()
Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook
Dim sourceRange As Excel.Range
Dim targetRange As Excel.Range



'## Open both workbooks first:

Set x = Workbooks("Svc-Op KPI Overall-6c.xlsm")

Set y = Workbooks("SEA Aftermarket Dashboard - Civic - Copy.xlsm")


 Set sourceRange = x.Sheets("Monthly").Range(Cells(26, 3), Cells(26, 14)) + x.Sheets("Monthly").Range(Cells(27, 3), Cells(27, 14))

 Set targetRange = y.Sheets("Data").Cells(38, 3)
  targetRange.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues,Operation:=xlNone,SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below:

```
Sub SumValues()
    Set sourceSheet = Worksheets("sheets with rows to sum")
    Set destSheet = Worksheets("sheet where results should pasted")
    For i = 3 To 12
        ' Write results to destSheet, starting in cell A1
        destSheet.Cells(i - 2, 1) = sourceSheet.Cells(26, i) + sourceSheet.Cells(27, i)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much Michal! it worked and i really appreciate your help. thank you once again.